# Building an Email Template

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs

UPDATE: It's not an answer, but I switched to mjml, as recommended in the comments, and that's a lot easier to work with for now, but if anyone knows the reason I'm encountering my current issue, feel free to help.

So, I'm building an email template, and to do this, I'm using a react component as that template. When I try using Preview.js to see what it might look like, I get something like this:

[image: Good Result]

That's what I want. However, when I send out the email, it looks like this in my inbox:
[image: Bad Result]

Does anyone know why this might be the case? For further clarification, a user inputs information in a modal dialog form. When they submit that form, the payload is then delivered to a Gmail API route, where the data is converted into what should be displayed on the email template. I will also include the API route, as that could be a source of the error.

Below is my email template file:

```
const EmailTemplate = ({
  alertType,
  alertStartDate,
  alertEndDate,
  alertLocations,
  alertLocationCodes,
  servicesAffected,
  alertDetails
}) => {
  const containerStyle = {
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100vw',
    background: '#FFF',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  };

  const innerContainerStyle = {
    width: '590px',
    height: '1025px',
    background: '#BD0F72',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  };

  const contentStyle = {
    width: '531px',
    height: '973px',
    background: '#FFF',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
  };

  const oneLogoStyle = {
    width: '254px',
    height: '97px',
    margin: '20px 10px 5px 10px',
  };

  const wavesContainerStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: '235px',
    bottom: 0,
  };

  const overlayStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: '200px',
    background: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%)',
  };

  const wavesStyle = {
    width: '531px',
    height: '235px',
  };

  const textBoxStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '80%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    padding: '10px',
    fontFamily: 'Proxima Nova, Arial, sans-serif',
    color: '#BD0F72',
    fontSize: '26px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  };

  const textContainerStyle = {
    padding: '20px',
    width: '100%',
  };

  const paragraphStyle = {
    color: '#BD0F72',
    fontSize: '20px',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 400,
    lineHeight: 'normal',
    fontFamily: 'Arial Black, Arial, sans-serif',
  };

  const spanStyle = {
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
  };

  const alertContentStyle = {
    fontSize: '12px',
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
  };

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div style={innerContainerStyle}>
        <div style={contentStyle}>
          <img style={oneLogoStyle} src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/ONE_LOGO.svg" />
          <div style={textContainerStyle}>
            <p>
              <b>Alert Type: </b><span style={spanStyle}>{alertType}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Alert Start Date: </b><span style={spanStyle}>{alertStartDate}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Alert End Date: </b><span style={spanStyle}>{alertEndDate}</span>
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Locations:</b>
              <p className="alert-content" style={alertContentStyle}>{alertLocations}</p>
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Location Codes:</b>
              <p className="alert-content" style={alertContentStyle}>{alertLocationCodes}</p>
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Services Affected:</b>
              <p className="alert-content" style={alertContentStyle}>{servicesAffected}</p>
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Alert Details:</b>
              <p className="alert-content" style={alertContentStyle}>{alertDetails}</p>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div style={wavesContainerStyle}>
            <div style={overlayStyle}></div>
            <img style={wavesStyle} src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1140148807/vector/paradise-white-sand-beach-and-sea-view-from-above.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=dCZUmHgFkIStcCeU6weQuZj6my9IBQccqXr1fRw2lEU=" />
            <div style={textBoxStyle}>AS ONE, WE CAN.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmailTemplate;
```

Here is the API Route:

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const {
        alertType,
        alertLocationData,
        alertSubject,
        alertDetails,
        userEmail,
        distributionEmail,
        alertStartDate,
        alertEndDate,
        attachments,
      } = req.body;

      const locationNames = []
      const locationCodes = []
      const servicesAffected = []

      alertLocationData.forEach(item => {
        const location = item['Location Name']
        const code = item['Code']
        const services = item['Services']

        locationNames.push(location)
        locationCodes.push(code)
        servicesAffected.push(services)
      });

      const emailContent = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
        <EmailTemplate
          alertType={alertType}
          alertStartDate={alertStartDate}
          alertEndDate={alertEndDate}
          alertLocations={locationNames}
          alertLocationCodes={locationCodes}
          servicesAffected={servicesAffected}
          alertDetails={alertDetails}
        />
      )

      const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
      const token = await getToken({ req })

      if (!session || !token || !token.accessToken) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' })
      }

      const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({})
      oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: token.accessToken,
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      });

      const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client })

      const sendEmail = async () => {
        try {
          const email = `From: <${userEmail}>\nTo: <YOUR EMAIL HERE>\nSubject: ${alertSubject}\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n${emailContent}`;

          const base64EncodedEmail = Buffer.from(email).toString('base64')
          const response = await gmail.users.messages.send({
            userId: 'me',
            requestBody: {
              raw: base64EncodedEmail,
            },
          })

          console.log(`Email Sent: ${response.data}`)

          return res.status(200).json({ success: true })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error sending email: ${error}`)
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send email' })
        }
      };

      await sendEmail();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`An error has occurred: ${error}`);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to run a react app in an email?

Comment: What exactly are you sending in the email?

Comment: read about https://mjml.io/ and then www.testi.at  litmus.com or www.emailonacid.com

Comment: @Sean @A Haworth I added some clarification to what I'm doing with the email template